# Reminder email for applicants

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have an application system where users can save their info but not submit. Obviously they need to be reminded if they haven't submitted everything before deadline.
The basic way I could do this is if it has been submitted then a field in my database can be marked as 1. However, if it is 0, I want an email to be sent to remind them.

To make it more complicated, starting from 4 weeks before deadline, I want 1 email that week, 3 weeks before deadline two emails and so on until they recieve four emails 1 week before deadline. (obviously spread out over the week).

I feel just one a week is probobly gonna be complicated enough for me as I'm still new!

Researching it looks as if I need a Cronjob but if there was anyway to avoid this (triggers), that would be better!

Comment: ugh, 4 emails in a week, I'd be pissed. But yeah you need a job to run every night to send out the emails update the database

Comment: Agreed, use a cron job. This is exactly what they're for. Adding more emails doesn't make it any harder; just have cron run a PHP script that queries the database, checks for people who meet your various criteria, and sends them the email. To reduce the chances of accidentally spamming someone, I would also have a table that stores a record for each email you've sent to each user, so you can make sure you don't send a user the same reminder email twice.

Comment: Any idea with the php script I need to create?

Comment: if the deadline is fixed for all users, your aproach would be best, however if the deadline depends on something else, you would be better with a date format of your choice instead of a 0-1; if by any chance your deadline depends on the registration date of the user, then just use that.

Comment: no the deadline will be the same for all

Answer (score 0):

Cron jobs are daunting at first and the associated process may look difficult, but can be broken into pieces. Also, the script will grow as you learn and think of things to include.  Not knowing your database structure, maybe an outline will get you started.

Decide how often to run the script (daily, every 6 hours, etc)

Many hosts use cPanel for management. It has an icon to work with Cron Jobs, and a choice of easy or expert setup modes. It may also have example settings. You will enter numbers for the day, month, year, hour and minute or * (asterisk) for including all possible numbers.

Another item difficult for beginners is the command to use to the tells the server how and what file to process. It took much reading, and trial & error.

An example: php -q /home/your_account_name/public_html/admin/yourfile_cron.php (the beginning may be different on your server) 

In the script:

(Use full path details to avoid problems later, like above starting with: /home...)

1. Set some constants (debugging file, database password file, etc)

   Use fopen & fwrite to record things that you won't see coming to the screen
2. Begin with a query to database to find the user's name and email for
   sending
3. Process the result query and its data
4. Build the email
5. Send the email

   Depending on server, choose mail program. On some, mail() won't send outside localhost. (PHP Mailer is an option)
6. Update the database with results of file running & send

You can run the script for testing by accessing it in a browser and including some 'echos'. A cron job doesn't usually have (or need) screen output.
During testing, I use a my own email as a static recipient.

Hope that gets you started. This is a large task, that will require days to implement. You'll find it rewarding though, when it finally does what you ask!!